# local cache hit metric in cuda profiler

Tags: cuda, nvprof

For some CUDA application profilings, I see that the value of local hit rate (local_hit_rate metric) is 0%.

I want to distinguish the following concepts with that value.

1. The application has no access to the local cache.
2. All accesses to local cache were misses.

How can I find the answer? Since the value of `inst_compute_ld_st`, `ldst_issued` and `ldst_executed` are non-zero, is it fine to discard the first question? Or there is something else?

The device is M2000 which is <strike>CC5.3</strike> CC5.2

Comment: M2000 is not cc5.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nvprof supports both events (raw counters) and metrics. These can be queried using the following commands:
nvprof --query-events
nvprof --query-metrics

CC5.*/6.* Local Memory Metircs

- **local_load_transactions_per_request**:  Average number of local memory load transactions performed for each local memory load
- **local_store_transactions_per_request**:  Average number of local memory store transactions performed for each local memory store
- **local_load_transactions**:  Number of local memory load transactions
- **local_store_transactions**:  Number of local memory store transactions
- **local_hit_rate**:  Hit rate for local loads and stores
- **local_memory_overhead**:  Ratio of local memory traffic to total memory traffic between the L1 and L2 caches expressed as percentage
- **local_load_throughput**:  Local memory load throughput
- **local_store_throughput**:  Local memory store throughput
- **inst_executed_local_loads**:  Warp level instructions for local loads
- **inst_executed_local_stores**:  Warp level instructions for local stores
- **l2_local_load_bytes**:  Bytes read from L2 for misses in Unified Cache for local loads
- **l2_local_global_store_bytes**:  Bytes written to L2 from Unified Cache for local and global stores. This does not include global atomics.
- **local_load_requests**:  Total number of local load requests from Multiprocessor
- **local_store_requests**:  Total number of local store requests from Multiprocessor

local_*_request is the number of instructions executed to local memory via generic address space or local address space. On CC5.*/6.* I do not recall if this includes fully predicated of instructions.

local_*_transactions is the number of cache accesses that occurred due to the size (32-bit, 64-bit, ...) of the request and the address divergence of the request. If this is non-zero then local memory was accessed.

l2_local_*_bytes is the number of bytes of data loaded/stored to the L2 cache.